# Cannot implicitly convert type to type parameter - C# generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have declared a method with input and output type parameters. I have put some constrainsts on these types. See code below.

```
class Input { public int I { get; set; } }
    class InputType1 : Input { }
    class InputType2 : Input { }

    class Output { public int O { get; set; } }
    class OutputType1 : Output { }

    static TOutput Method<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input) 
        where TInput : Input 
        where TOutput : Output
    {
        var output = new Output() { O = input.I * 2 };
        return output; //  compile error: connot do conversion implicitly
    }
```

Why does the conversion can be done implicitly on the variable 'input' and not on the variable 'output'?

Comment: Not every `Output` will be a `TOutput`. This can never work, what are you trying to do? Do you maybe want to return `Output`? Or do you want to constrain `TOutput` to `new()` so you can call `new TOutput() { O = input.I * 2 };`?

Comment: @Joelius I want to return the type Output or any of its derivatives. Maybe i'll return an Output type or TOutput. I understood why the conversion is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot infer out the concrete type of `Output`. The only thing the compiler knows the return type is some type that inherits from `Output`.

To create an instance of `TOuptut` change your code to

```cs
static TOutput Method<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input) 
        where TInput : Input 
        where TOutput : Output, new()
    {
        var output = new TOutput() { O = input.I * 2 };
        return output;
    }
```

Note the `new()` constraint requires that a parameterless constructor must exist on `TOutput`.